# How to bind exception class and error code of external com exception?

Tags: c#, exception, com

my .NET application calls method of object that located out of assembly boundaries. When this method has thrown exception i've catched COMException.

Exception contains special code in ErrorCode field, for example -123.

try
{
// call outside object
}
catch(COMException e)
{
  // e.ErrorCode == -123;
}

Is it posible to define exception class that will be thrown instead of COMException?

eg

[ErrorCode of external error = -123]
public class MyException : Exception;

and rewrite above code

try
{
// call outside object
}
catch(MyException e)
{
  //...
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is it posible to define exception class that will be thrown instead of COMException?"

No, but you could catch the COMException, wrap it in a custom exception class, and rethrow it.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

I considered this decision, but i've got many sevices that were written on delphi. Now i need use them on c#.

Each of delphi-services requires personally wrapper that will be catch all com exception and will throw predetermined c# exception.

When delphi-services will changed or some new delphi-exception will be added, i will need to modify wrappers. It's sad.